# Pi3 not detecting wifi or ethernet. How to connect Internet to Pi3

Tags: wifi, raspbian, raspberry-pi3, ethernet

When I place the cursor to network connection at the panel which is two red cross marks on a parallel line it says..

eth0: Link is down
wlan0: Not associated

When I tried to connect a Ethernet cable directly it detected the IP and said configured..But I am unable to browse giving error..the site cant be reached.

I tried connecting through wifi by adding lines of user and password in wpa-supplicant file.

Is there any problem with the software or hardware?

Please help me to solve the issue.

Comment: Connect the ethernet cable in a PC and check if network (browser) is working fine.

Comment: I will check it

Comment: No..It was just detecting

Comment: With same cable site can be reached on PC?

Comment: But why is wifi not working? It works in PC

Comment: Nope..It was just showed connected but when I tried to comment it did not work..

Comment: Ok, if cable is not browsing on PC with cable you should configure network to work on PC then connect raspberry, it is a safe start before wifi. If you want Wi-Fi directly and is connected with monitor click Wi-Fi icon in graphic interface upper right side of screen

Comment: oh ok..I will try to do that way.Thanks a lot for your suggestion..:)

Answer (score 0):

After connecting your Ethernet cable from modem to pi,..In the wired and wireless settings in pi3,select interface -> eth0 and select (tick)automatically configure empty options. 
Do not enter any information in the below boxes like ip adress,router,dns server,dns search.